# Indexing pdf with Apache solr to get page Number on search in pdf

Tags: java, apache, pdf, solr, lucene

I am new to apache lucene 
I have written code for Indexing pdf file using apache lucene and am able to search text which gives me only the document name where the search string is found. I used pdfbox to extract the text and index it but how to index the pdf text page wise. I found Field collapsing to get page number in the pdf document but seems bit confusing.

How to search the index for a phrase, getting not only the
document name , but also the page number in the pdf document using apache lucene. Any sample code will or any reference will be highly appreciated

Any sample code or any refernce will be highly appreciated

Comment: You could just index each page as a separate document.

Comment: Have a read in [the blog of Hathitrust](https://www.hathitrust.org/blogslarge-scale-search)